# Add Product Short description in Order Confirmation Email - Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I need to get the product short description to display on its own in the order confirmation email.

Can any one help me?

Thanks

Running PS 1.7.5.0

Comment: Please read and see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, also provide what you have tried so far and where you are stuck? it is not okay to ask complete piece of working code and hoping somebody will write it for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "***ActionEmailAddAfterContent***" Hook to add/update the content of any email in the Prestashop.

The hook is defined in the Mail.php Class.

For Prestashop 1.6:

```
Hook::exec('actionEmailAddAfterContent', array(
   'template' => $template,
   'template_html' => &$template_html,
   'template_txt' => &$template_txt,
   'id_lang' => (int)$id_lang
   ), null, true);
```

`$template` is *template name* like order_conf

`$template_html` is *template HTML* content